# Compare sets of values from two files and print the output in a third file using awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a problem comparing two files. I'll try my best to explain. I have two files *f1* and *f2* which I have to compare on basis of two sets *Parameter(p)* and *Value(v)*.

Basically *f1* contains a list of Values and Time Stamp for each of the Parameters

```
  f1.csv
  P,V,TS
  p1,12,10:10:00
  p2,34,10:21:00
  p1,12,10:21:00
  p2,34,10:22:00 
  p1,60,10:35:00
  p3,60,10:36:00
  p4,22,10:38:00
  p4,42,10:40:00    
  p1,60,10:41:00
  p3,58,10:42:00
  p2,55,10:45:00
  p3,58,10:55:00
```

File *f2* contains the previous/latest value and time stamp for each parameter. Every parameter has only one occurrence in this file. For clarity, RTS(Real Time Stamp) & UTS(Updated Time Stamp).

```
  f2.csv
  P,V,RTS,UTS
  p1,12,10:00:00,10:05:00
  p2,34,10:07:00,10:15:00
  p3,60,10:25:00,10:30:00
  p4,22,10:30:00,10:32:00
```

Now I will try to explain the output in two parts.
The first part is easy: for similar (P,V) in f1 & f2, change the UTS with the latest TS. Here is pseudo code:

```
  for each (P, V) in f1
  {
  #if value exists in f2
  if ((P, V) exists in f2)
  { 
   f2.RTS(P,V)=f2.RTS(P,V)
   f2.UTS(P, V) = f1.TS(P, V)
  } 
  }
```

For the value which exists in f2 and f1 first part of the o/p file f3 in []:-

```
 f3.csv

 [ P,V,RTS,UTS
   p1,12,10:00:00,10:10:00
   p2,34,10:07:00,10:21:00
   p1,12,10:00:00,10:21:00
   p2,34,10:07:00,10:22:00 
   p3,60,10:25:00,10:36:00
   p4,22,10:30:00,10:38:00]
```

The second part is difficult. It deals only with f1 file: Values which do not exist in f2.

For values from f1 (p4,42,10:40:00)(p2,55,10:45:00) which occur only once and are not in f2 should have RTS=UTS=TS as given in output shown below.

Example:-For a single occurrence

```
   p4,42,10:40:00,10:40:00
```

For values  (p3,58,10:42:00),(p3,58,10:55:00),(p1,60,10:35:00)(p1,60,10:41:00) which occur twice and are not in f2,the first occurrence should have RTS=UTS=TS and the second occurrence for same (P,V) should have RTS=(TS of first occurrence of (P,V)) and UTS=TS of second occurrence of (P,V).

Example: First occurrence (p1,60) in f1.

```
 p1,60,10:35:00,10:35:00
```

Second occurrence (p1,60) in f1

```
 p1,60,10:35:00,10:41:00
```

The second part expected output:

```
  f3.csv
 [ P,V,RTS,UTS
   p1,60,10:35:00,10:35:00
   p4,42,10:40:00,10:40:00
   p1,60,10:35:00,10:41:00
   p3,58,10:42:00,10:42:00
   p2,55,10:45:00,10:45:00
   p3,58,10:42:00,10:55:00]
```

Final output is appending both the output CSV files.

Thank you any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain this any better? Please?

Comment: @mikeserv I am sorry which part did you not understand.I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I used perl here, as it has more flexible data structures (hash of hashes of arrays).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use autodie;

my (%f1, @order);
open my $fh, "<", "f1.csv";
while (<$fh>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    chomp;
    my ($p, $v, $ts) = split /,/;
    push @{ $f1{$p}{$v} }, $ts;
    push @order, [$p, $v];
}
close $fh;

my %f2;
open $fh, "<", "f2.csv";
while (<$fh>) {
    print if $. == 1;
    chomp;
    my ($p, $v, $rts, $uts) = split /,/;
    $f2{$p}{$v} = [$rts, $uts];
}
close $fh;

for my $key (@order) {
    my ($p, $v) = @$key;
    if (exists $f2{$p}{$v}) {
        my $uts = shift @{$f1{$p}{$v}}
        say join(",", $p, $v, $f2{$p}{$v}[0], $uts);
    }
}

my @remaining;
for my $p (keys %f1) {
    for my $v (keys %{$f1{$p}}) {
        my ($rts, $uts) = @{$f1{$p}{$v}};
        push @remaining, [$p, $v, $rts, $rts] if $rts;
        push @remaining, [$p, $v, $rts, $uts] if $rts and $uts;
    }
}
say for map {join ",", @{$_->[1]}} 
        sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]} 
        map {[$_->[3], $_]} 
        @remaining;
```

Running it produces:

```
P,V,RTS,UTS
p1,12,10:00:00,10:10:00
p2,34,10:07:00,10:21:00
p1,12,10:00:00,10:21:00
p2,34,10:07:00,10:22:00
p3,60,10:25:00,10:36:00
p4,22,10:30:00,10:38:00
p1,60,10:35:00,10:35:00
p4,42,10:40:00,10:40:00
p1,60,10:35:00,10:41:00
p3,58,10:42:00,10:42:00
p2,55,10:45:00,10:45:00
p3,58,10:42:00,10:55:00
```

Comment: i dont know much about perl but i'll try.thank you very much.

Comment: give it try. This isn't the easiest perl to read. You can start with `perldoc perl` but `perldoc perlreftut` will help you with my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code with some help form my friend.Just for some reference.Cheers

```
  #!/bin/awk -f
  BEGIN{
      FS=","; 
      OFS=",";
       }
      {
             if(NR==FNR)
             {
                a[var]=$1" "$2
                ts[var]=$3
                var++   
              }else if(NR>FNR)
            {
            b[sec]=$1" "$2
            rt[sec]=$3
            ut[sec]=$4
            sec++
            } 
     }
  END{  
  #Code for first part of the o/p
         for(i=0;i<var;i++)
           {
          for(j=0;j<sec;j++)
           {
          if(!(a[i]<b[j]||a[i]>b[j]))
          {   m[a[i]]=1
             print a[i]" "rt[j]" "ts[i]
           }
             }      
           }
  #Code for second part of the o/p
         for(i=0;i<var;i++)
         {
         if(m[a[i]]!=1)
         {
             h[a[i]]++  

            if(h[a[i]]==1)
            {
                rts[a[i]]=ts[i]
                print rts[a[i]]
                print a[i]" "ts[i]" "ts[i]
            }
           else{
                print a[i]" "rts[a[i]]" "ts[i]
                }
          }
          }
      }
```